# Convert date time to day zero php

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, date-conversion, date-manipulation

one question to converting datetime type from mysql which range starts from 1001-01-01 00:00. 
Problem is the day starts from 1 day but I would like to have it from 0 days.
When I subtract day with -1 I get day 30.

```
$data['duration'] = date('d - H:i', strtotime($data['duration']));
```

This will output 01 - 00:00 but I would like to have 00 - 00:00

Any ideas ?

Comment: I'm not really sure but i don't think there is an 0 day.

Comment: @Bogdan There is a 0 day; it's the *"Big Bang"*.

Comment: true but not related to his question.

Comment: ok guys thanks :D but you know what I wanted to achieve - start with 0 days and only hours and then add days

Answer (score 0):

As i've as a comment there is no 0 day. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html

> The DATE type is used for values with a date part but no time part.
>   MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. The
>   supported range is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'.
>
> The DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time
>   parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD
>   HH:MM:SS' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to
>   '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.
>
> The TIMESTAMP data type is used for values that contain both date and
>   time parts. TIMESTAMP has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to
>   '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC.

Also

> Invalid DATE, DATETIME, or TIMESTAMP values are converted to the
>   “zero” value of the appropriate type ('0000-00-00' or '0000-00-00
>   00:00:00').
>
> MySQL does not accept TIMESTAMP values that include a zero in the day
>   or month column or values that are not a valid date. The sole
>   exception to this rule is the special “zero” value '0000-00-00
>   00:00:00'.

Answer (score 0):

Question answered - if hours are greater than 24 hours = I will display also 1 day.
Otherwise only time is displayed